# What is the chronological order of Warcraft canon media?

Tags: canon, warcraft, chronological-order

I guess I can assume Warcraft 3 and all WoW games are official canon, but what about books, mangas, and other stuff?

Also, most of Warcraft and Warcraft II got retconed, right?

So what is the chronological order of the Warcraft media?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I once looked into this and it's an incredibly difficult task to summarize as there are contradictions, changes, retcons and now an alternate timeline.    You also have numerous canon short stories posted to the website, in game events that overlap with the comic books and more.   Some parts, such as the RPG books are at times no longer considered canon.    That said, I've yet to see an official Star Wars-type declaration of official status for this universe.

Wow Wiki is a good resource for trying to manage this as they generally link to the short stories, take into account beginning and end dates for events that overlap and show all 14 current iterations.

The master list is [here](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_(unofficial)).

The list of all timelines is [here](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline), and is broken into the following areas:

Timeline (unofficial)
Main    Timeline with an attempt to be based on all sources of information and all versions of the timeline. May not be consistent with the latest official timeline.

Alternate
Split timeline created by altering Draenor of the past when Garrosh Hellscream diverted the Dark Portal into a time portal.

Timeline
(from official site, 2010)
Timeline based on the official site (2007) timeline with added dates.

Timeline
(from official site, 2007)
Timeline based on the official site (2004) timeline with added dates.

Timeline (TBC)
Timeline of dates established in The Burning Crusade and its manual (2007).

Timeline (PG)
Timeline and dates published in the RPG "Player's Guides", Alliance Player's Guide, Horde Player's Guide (2006), and Dark Factions (2008).

Timeline (Cycle of Hatred)
Timeline of dates established in Cycle of Hatred (2006).

Timeline (Lands of Mystery)
List of dates mentioned in Lands of Mystery (2006).

Timeline (WoWRPG)
Timeline published in World of Warcraft The Roleplaying Game in 2005.

Timeline (Lands of Conflict)
Timeline published in Lands of Conflict in 2004.

Timeline
(from official site, 2004)
Timeline released on the World of Warcraft website in 2004.

Timeline (WoWOSG)
Timeline published in the World of Warcraft Official Strategy Guide in 2004.

Timeline (WRPG)
Timeline published in Dungeons & Dragons: Warcraft: The Roleplaying Game in 2003.

Timeline (RTS)
Timeline originally published by Blizzard in the Warcraft I manual (1994), with further dates established from the Warcraft II manual (1996), Beyond the Dark Portal manual, and Warcraft III manual. Also includes dates mentioned in the RTS games themselves.

Timeline
(RPG Books Chronology)
This article discusses the chronological order of books in the Warcraft RPG and World of Warcraft RPG from 2003 to present.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Warcraft lore the ultimate source is World Of Warcraft itself and supporting documents on the website.

After that all games, books, manga, and comics by/licensed by blizard are cannon . However, these all have inconsistencies or pieces of the story that are later tweaked, retconned, or changed in world of warcraft itself. Some of the newest media is fairly accurate and may have little to no issues currently but thr father back you go from live WOW the more likely issues will arise.

Comment: This does not address the chronological order at all.

Comment: @Theik i answered his second question, what is canon.

Comment: How do you know that what is in WoW trumps what is in other games? And if there is an inconsistency, what determines the 'truth'?